# How to call a selector in a different class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, class, methods, selector

How would this code be different if the method was in a different class?

```
[saveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveArray) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pass the object (which responds to the method) as the target parameter.

```
[saveButton addTarget:targetObj action:@selector(saveArray) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 5):

You'd have to replace `self` with an instance of the other class.